# Display Outlook rooms occupancy in a web page

Tags: java, asp.net, resources, outlook

I'm decommissioning a meeting room scheduling [web] tool in favor of the same Outlook's functionality.
I'd like, however, to publish (read-only) a "Group Schedule" view in a web page.

To make the idea more clear:

On Outlook's Calendar view, select Actions / View Group Schedules and then create a new group for say, Conference Rooms.
This new view will give a global view of Conference Rooms occupancy. I need a way to publish this room's occupancy.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For Exchange 2007 and onward come with a handy web service API. A good place to start on that would be to check out the [Exchange Web Services Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286.aspx).

However, if you're using an older version of Exchange, I think you'll have to look into WebDAV.
I've only retrieved calendar events from Exchange 2003, and it was pretty messy. A good article on WebDav can be found over at [Marc Charbonneau’s Blog](http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/).

Not a complete answer to your question, but it might be a start.

Comment: I was trying to avoid coding for this particular case, since I'm just trying to give my users a handy and convenient way to consult room availability. I'll evaluate my available effort for this one, and if I opt for the WS client dev, I'll keep the thread up-to-date. Thanks, Marcus.

Comment: For some reason beyond my current understanding and scope, I have no "GetRooms" Operation - or related -  in Exchange's wsdl. I would go for a webservice client development but I found that this would interface other teams and I really don't need to distract them ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Outlook Guru, but if you use an iCal (?) calendar provider on the web, like the ones on Live.com, you can view them in Outlook.